# Someone is copying my website on a different domain

Tags: php, server

Someone is copying my website live.

my: https://english-subtitles.org/
copy: http://steemitup.eu/

I've tried everything.
Redirection in the index.php file does not work.
JS redirection does not work because it cuts all the js from the page.

SSH login with the key.
All passwords changed (admin, ftp, web panel).

When I upload a picture to the server with him, he is also.

https://english-subtitles.org/a.png
http://steemitup.eu/a.png

The IP address assigned to the domain is blocked but it still works.

How to deal with this?

Please forgive me for poor English.

---

From what I see, they use CURL.
Such a mistake is with them when I turned off my website:

> Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Is it possible to block it somehow?

---

EDIT

Problem solved!

The best option was to use CloudFlare Firewall.
Searching for the v6 IP address in the logs and blocking it.

Comment: Are there any more users to SSH that may have access?

Comment: I think this should be moved to Serverfault.com

Comment: Only I have access to SSH

Comment: Did you double check? Maybe someone got root access to your server and created a backdoor user.

Comment: To get to the server you need to use a key.

Comment: You might want to run [this script](https://gist.github.com/jasperf/3191259) on your command line and pipe it's output into an HTML file. This looks for suspicious code in all the files and directories inside the one you are running this script from. But be aware. This script searches for patterns only, and creates many false positives. There is much work to be done scanning through the results of this script.

Comment: For every user? I would double check on this. If you've been hacked, what seems to be the case, you shouldn't take things for granted without checking

Comment: I will run the script in a moment.

Comment: Did you try to upload a totally obfuscated file like `fasd8s9fsdhfjsgfkj/fsdjkfhsdlfkdjsklgdjfd.txt` to your server and check if that appears on the clone server, too? If, then after what time period?

Comment: fasd8s9fsdhfjsgfkj/fsdjkfhsdlfkdjsklgdjfd.txt works on clone

Comment: http://steemitup.eu//fasd8s9fsdhfjsgfkj/fsdjkfhsdlfkdjsklgdjfd.txt

Comment: Then you should check this. 1. Create a new obfuscated file, 2. Don't access this file on your own site. 3. Be sure you have access to your server access log file 4.Try to reach your new file through the clone site. 5. Watch your access log for new traffic on that file

Comment: Looking for bad guys script. I glued to the site because here I can not do so many characters.

https://pastecode.xyz/view/69d039b4

Comment: I found this one: https://steemit.com/steem/@steemychicken1/steemitup

Comment: This is a completely different area of the site. I'll check the logs soon,

Comment: You shouldn't have published the lookforbagguys result. It may reveal security holes on your site

Comment: Nothing in the logs

Comment: 195.225.146.131 - - [23/Jan/2019:13:31:17 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3074 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"

Comment: BTW. These 2 files look suspicious:  
`/home/admin/english-subtitles.org/i.php` and
`/home/admin/english-subtitles.org/grabb/englishtvs.php`

Comment: I run only on clone and see in nginx log 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2019:13:57:30 +0100] "GET /fasd38s9fsdfRERphhdh432h7765fjsgfkj/fsdjkfgfmgfdwsaawddrehsdlfkdjsklgdjfd.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)

Comment: i.php is TimThumb and englishtvs.php this is my script

Comment: Is it possible to block it somehow?

Answer (score 6):

My prediction is he is just get the url that request to his server and then he curl to your site get the element in the site and replace some of your stuff with his stuff so that why there is a "realtime copying".

The solution could be you load his site and check the access log from your server to get the "someone"'s ip and then block it.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. They probably have a clever scrape script + VPNs to make their traffic difficult to trace. Look at your visitor access logs and see if you can see patterns like IP addresses at certain times, browser finger prints, what pages they visited, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have a security breach.

What I think the copycat does:

1. Have a rewrite configuration on his webserver (nginx) that always starts a script on all none existing files on his site
2. This script will fetch the content with the same URL path from your site (and caches it)
3. It will transforms the fetched output (HTML) with his own logo and domain links
4. Output the transformed data

### What you can do?

Check your access log for the IP address. Block that IP address!

### If they change IP addresses?

1. Keep checking for suspicious IP access
   You could create a script that regularly requests random gibberish resources onthe copycat domain and watches the access log for that gibberish path and then automatically block that IP (if you are allowed to)

Comment: clone use IP 93.179.121.114 but i don't see in access log (httpd,nginx)

Comment: It's not necessary the same IP. They could use proxies. Check for any IP address in your access log. Just request some gibberish URL from the copycat like http://steemitup.eu/fjskjfhkjfhsdkddhfgdfsglhfksdofiisofrjgiadsofdk and search for that path in your logs

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2019:14:12:51 +0100] "GET /fjskjfhkjfhsdkddhfgdfsglhfksdofiisofrjgiadsofdk HTTP/1.1" 200 3069 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36" "2a01:4f8:200:81a3:0:0:0:2, 162.158.89.42"

Comment: Is it possible to block it somehow?

Comment: It seems they use a script on your server as a proxy

Comment: Search for the navigator string (or part of) on your server: `grep -rile 'AppleWebKit' / 2> /dev/null`. And search for files created before Mon, 19 Sep 2016 06:37:40 GMT, because that is the time the Copycats Logo was created (or modified): `touch -t 201609190637.40 a_file_to_provide_a_timestamp; find / -type f -cnewer a_file_to_provide_a_timestamp 2> /dev/null`

Comment: You can try to block `127.0.0.1`. But this should only be temporary to test for applicability

Comment: I block 127.0.0.1 http://steemitup.eu/      https://english-subtitles.org/   503 error on the clone there is also a visit counter

Comment: The 127 seems to be the varnish

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any l´time left to assist you

Comment: I understand,
Thank you for your help.